# Xcode - Navigation controller tutorial needed

Tags: xcode, controller, xib, nib, navigationcontroller

Does anyone have a good navigation controller tutorial for newer Xcodes that still uses xib file instead of storyboard? I've been searching everywhere, and what I've found either is for Xcode version 2.0 or either uses storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_a_Navigation_based_iOS_5_iPhone_Application_using_TableViews

Should give you the basic idea... Written for iOS 5 though, so some functions might need updating